# Count the number of occurrences from a list of substrings in Excel

Tags: excel

I have these columns with these lists of phrases:

```
Column A             Column B  

cat dog mouse        cat
cat mouse car        dog
dog can              mouse
tree cat dog dog  
tree
```

I want to count the number of words in B that occur in each of the phrases in A, so the result would be:

```
cat dog mouse      3  
cat mouse car      2  
dog can            1  
tree cat dog dog   3  
tree               0
```

How would I do this?

Comment: choose a different tool :-)

Comment: start [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each word in list B will only ever appear in once in each line of the values in list A.

Put the values in list A in column A (starting from cell A2)
Put the values in cells in row A (starting form cell B1 as headers)

Copy and paste this formula to Cell B2 then copy it over and down.

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND(B$1,$A:$A)),0,1)
```

Adding row totals will give you the count you need.

This case sensitive.